# Remove nth row in R data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 1- minute measurements for things like humidity, soil temperatures, air temp, irradiance etc (14 Columns and about 35000 rows).

I would like to remove every nth row so the sampling interval would be greater say 3o mins etc, this also speeds up the process when i join all the frames together to create a data frame for the year.

Is there anyway I can have R automatically delete every nth row? without specifying each row number?
This is a sample of the data frame.

```
                 V1    V2    V3     V4      V5       V6      V7       V8     V9    V10    V11    V12    V13    V14
1     2012-11-01 00:00:00 24587 13.16  9.260   0.028    0.016   0.013    0.009  8.200  7.643  8.370  67.66 13.930 14.910
2     2012-11-01 00:01:00 24588 13.16  9.250   0.024    0.011   0.009    0.008  8.220  7.725  8.380  67.24 13.930 14.910
3     2012-11-01 00:02:00 24589 13.15  9.250   0.025    0.009   0.011    0.004  8.240  7.741  8.390  67.12 13.930 14.910
4     2012-11-01 00:03:00 24590 13.15  9.240   0.022    0.007   0.007    0.011  8.210  7.695  8.390  67.48 13.930 14.910
5     2012-11-01 00:04:00 24591 13.16  9.230   0.025    0.011   0.010    0.006  8.190  7.689  8.380  67.82 13.930 14.910
6     2012-11-01 00:05:00 24592 13.16  9.230   0.024    0.009   0.010    0.012  8.170  7.672  8.360  68.03 13.930 14.910
7     2012-11-01 00:06:00 24593 13.16  9.220   0.029    0.011   0.008    0.011  8.170  7.685  8.350  67.71 13.930 14.910
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of diffrent ways to do that, a simple one is this:

```
# make an index eg. every 3th
ind <- seq(1, nrow(df), by=3)

# make subset --> this would choose every `ind` row
df[ind, ]

# --> this would exclude ale `ind` row
df[-ind, ]
```

hth